# Си. Объявление динамического двумерного массива

Tags: c, динамические-массивы

Я изучаю объявление двумерных динамических массивов в Си. Я полагал, что динамические массивы здесь можно объявлять только с помощью ссылок и malloc().

Сначала я использовал malloc() в цикле.

```
int m, n, c;
scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);

int** a = (int**)malloc(m*sizeof(int*));

for (c = 0; c < m; c++) {
  a[c] = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
}
```

Затем пришёл к единственному вызову malloc().

```
int m, n, c;
scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);

int** a = (int**)malloc(m*sizeof(int*) + m*n*sizeof(int));

int* row = &a[n];

for (c = 0; c < m; row += n, c++) {
  a[c] = row;
}
```

А потом попробовал элементарное:

```
int m, n;
scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);

int a[m][n];
```

И это сработало. Это нормально? Этим можно пользоваться?

Comment: в последнем примере у вас двумерный массив будет не динамический, а статический. Это будет работать нормально, но память будет выделяться на стеке.

Answer (score 1):

Если под динамическим подразумевается массив, размер которого может меняться во время компиляции, то без `malloc` не обойтись.

Если нужен массив, размер которого определяется в run-time, то записать `int a[m][n]` можно. Память выделится локально на стеке, но размер массива нельзя будет сменить.

Это нормальная практика, но нужно иметь ввиду, что в `С++` такой возможности нет.

Comment: В С++ для этого можно использовать другие возможности :) Я верно понимаю, что основная неприятность с массивами переменной длины в C - что они размещаются в стеке? Просто VC++ 2015 эту возможность поддерживать не хочет, так что знания чисто теоретические...

Comment: @Harry, массив, объявленный как `int a[m][n]` - это массив фиксированной размерности. Если объявить массив глобально, то он будет храниться в области глобальных переменных, если в функции - то будет храниться в стеке.

Comment: @insolor Фиксированной уже при рантайме, так? Когда будут введены значения n и m?

Comment: @Harry, насколько я помню, n и m как раз должны быть известны на момент компиляции (не в ран-тайме).

Comment: @insolor Здесь как раз речь идет о новшестве в C - массивах с переменным размером, когда m и n не обязаны быть константами времени компиляции. Вот мне и интересно, как это решается на практике...

Comment: @Harry, по-моему, динамические массивы в Си объявляются вообще без размеров (и размер их можно будет изменять), но не могу утверждать со 100% уверенность. Здесь int3 скорее всего имел в виду как раз статические размеры, просто ошибся со временем определения его размера.

Comment: Хотя я могу ошибаться. Нужно будет сесть почитать стандарты Си.

Comment: @insolor динамических массивов в си вообще нет, как я знаю. Массивы с run-time размером статичны в том смысле, что размер задается единожды, а память выделяется через alloca (если я не ошибаюсь). Как дело обстоит с глобальными - не знаю, но с большой вероятностью, их размеры должны быть известны во время компиляции.

Comment: @int3, да, уже разобрался. Нужно будет поиграться с этим, посмотреть как это в ассемблерном виде будет выглядеть. Ну и пробелы в знаниях нужно восполнять мне)

Comment: @insolor провёл небольшой эксперимент: http://pastebin.com/c2JfCGMX